# How can I extend cases in reducers with Redux ToolKit?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am making a plugin where there are some universal actions that can be handled in a reducer. I am unsure how to make it so someone can extend for additional cases with the same action. I have some code like this:

```js
export default function createStore() {
  return configureStore({
    preloadedState: initialStoreState,
    reducer: {
      workingStores: workingStoreReducer,
    },
  });
}
```

The reducer is what you would expect:

```js
export default createReducer(initialWorkingStoreState, (builder) => {
  builder
    // chained for a number of actions rather than just one in reality
    .addCase(anImportedAction, (state, { payload }) => {});
```

Essentially someone using my plugin may have additional actions to modify the state of `workingStores`.

I am thinking of solving the problem in a seemingly complicated way where `createStore` could take a callback, and then my `workingStoreReducer` becomes a method of `getWorkingStoreReducer` which would take that callback...

```js
export default function getWorkingStoreReducer(extensions) {
  return createReducer(initialWorkingStoreState, (builder) => {
    exensions(builder); // method would add cases to builder
    builder.addCase(anImportedAction, (state, { payload }) => {}); 

  });
}
```

This seems convoluted so hoping there is a simpler thing I have missed in the docs

Comment: Can you import all actions as a namespace?

Comment: @Summer can you clarify that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask is it possible to do something like `import * as actions from '...'`. Then it shouldn't be difficult to iterate over the `actions` namespace. You won't even need the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the extension method I proposed in OG question. I couldn't find a significantly different answer.

My Reducer:

```js
export default function getReducer(extension?: Function) {
  return createReducer<number | null>(null, (builder) => {
    if (typeof extension === 'function') {
      extension(builder);
    }

    builder
      .addCase(eventNewDocAction, (_, { payload }) => {
        const { workingDocumentId } = payload;

        return workingDocumentId;
      })
      .addCase(
        eventCloseDocAction,
        (_, { payload }) => payload.workingDocumentId,
      );
  });
}
```

My method that gets passed as `extension` to the above

```js
export default function (builder) {
  builder.addCase(eventGenericAction, (state, { payload }) => {
    const { documentData, evt } = payload;
    const { workingDocumentId } = documentData;
    const evtName = evt.name as EventType;

    if (activeDocumentEvents.has(evtName)) {
      return workingDocumentId;
    }

    // noop
    return state;
  });
}
```

Then for my `reducer` key in `configureStore` I have this:

```js
// extension.workingDocumentId is the above method that adds eventGenericAction
workingDocumentId: getWorkingDocumentIdReducer(
        extensions.workingDocumentId ?? undefined,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Is composing the builder callback ahead of time an option?

```js
// Your code
export const createBuilder = (additionalCases = []) => builder => {
    builder.addCase(anImportedAction, (state, { payload }) => {})
        .addCase(anImportedAction, (state, { payload }) => {})

    additionalCases.forEach(([action, reducer]) => builder.addCase(action, reducer)
}

const workingStoreReducer = createReducer(initialWorkingState, createBuilder());
```

Elsewhere, extend cases and rebuild the reducer

```js
const builderCallback = createBuilder([
  [anExtendedAction, (state, { payload }) => {}],
  [anExtendedAction, (state, { payload }) => {}],
]);
const workingStoreReducer = createReducer(workingState, builderCallback);

// Replace store reducer
```

Comment: Is there a reason to do it this way vs the way I wrote in question? I was about to put my way as the answer as that's what I ended up doing.